# While Exporting from SDE, null geometry features attack?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, error, export

I'm working on a layer in an SDE Database (ArcMap 10.1 SP1 for desktop (Build 3143)), I just export to a local working database on my workstation the layer I want to work on and load it back when done.

The problem is that when I export it seems that the records are exported fine (as I checked the tables) but on the map most of the points didn't appear.

The same layer appears normally on the ArcCatalog, but when exported the error happens.

- The check geometry results "null geometry”, the Repair Geometry" didn't solve it.
- Copying the Features to a new layer, result in the copying of the Features is that it copies the features with geometry and deletes the "null geometry".

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: - Exporting to Shapefile also didn't work.

Comment: What type is the local working database?  How are you exporting the feature class?  Does the last bullet point say that when you copy the feature class from your local working database, the null features are back to their original values?

Comment: Thanks Travis for the reply, well its a local file geodatabase, I export by right-click layer...Export...To Geodatabase(multiple)...even in single there is no bullet point about Null features, what is the method that you use for exporting?

Comment: I don't usually follow this workflow.  Generally I edit the feature class on the server.  When I need to move items around, I use Copy and Paste.